# How to fix data types time and datetime incompatiblity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I am trying to set some variables and create a procedure that will produce different type of table in each case of the statement. The conditions are dependent on date data types, and I get the error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure epSP, Line 50 [Batch Start Line
>   0] The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater
>   than or equal to operator.

The code that I've added is not the whole code. It is a part of a longer statement with an IF statement.
I've tried to add date data types before the different parts of the procedures and change the date after the < operator to a select statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE epSP

@StartDate DATETIME, 
@EndDate DATETIME,
@CompanyID INT 

AS

SET @StartDate = '2019-04-04 00:00:00' 
SET @EndDate = '2019-04-11 00:00:00'
SET @CompanyID = 1234567

BEGIN
    (CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME) < @StartDate)
    (
    SELECT  sa.CompanyID,
        sa.EmployeeID,
        sm.Day,
        sa.Date,
        sm.ShiftType,
        sm.StartTime,
        sm.EndTime
    FROM ShiftArrangement sa
    LEFT JOIN ShiftManagement sm
    ON (sa.SHIFTID = sm.ShiftID)
    WHERE sa.CompanyID = @CompanyID
    AND sa.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    )
```

The expected result is the SELECT statement according to the date given in the variable defined in the beginning of the statement. Actually the code doesn't return any value.

Comment: so it should look like `IF (GETDATE() < @StartDate) BEGIN ... END` right ?

Comment: It seems like the "ShiftArrangement" tables Date column is defined as a "Time" data type. But you compare the "Time" data type with datetime data type (the between statement). You can get more info on the data types here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: You don't need to cast `GETDATE()` as a `DATETIME`. The function already returns a `DATETIME` datatype.

Comment: Can you provide a sample schema and data that reflects your tables above? Also, which version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: You should probably change the name of `ShiftArrangement.Date` and `ShiftManagement.Day` to words that aren't special words in SQL and are more descriptive of what they are.  I'm not sure what `Day` is, but `Date` appears to be `TIME` datatype, which is not likely compatible with what that column is meant to hold. Even if you do manage to convert `sa.Date` to a format with a date and not just a time, it also likely won't fall between any `@StartDate` or `@EndDate` that didn't happen on 1/1/1900. We need some example data and expectations of output to help.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line:   `(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATETIME) < @StartDate)`?    It's invalid syntax the way you have it, and your intent isn't clear.